# Error Adding Bootstrap Into Angular Project

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

Trying to run this in my Angular project

`ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

Get this error though and don't know how to fix

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: paxium-contacts@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@15.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"15.0.4" from @angular/compiler-cli@15.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!     dev @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@ngtools/webpack)
npm ERR!   1 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular/localize@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler@15.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"15.1.0" from @angular/localize@15.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!     dev @angular/localize@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Comment: try to run `ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --force` command.

Comment: No, I wanted to fix the issue rather than force it.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: No fixes for this.  I have moved on though and just created a new project and added bootstrap first and all ok so don't really need this anymore.  What is the protocol with the question?

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm using angular 15.1.0 in a new project, and i'm getting the same error. I tried using --force  and it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) you have related the versions of ng-bootstrap for each version of Angular.

```
ng-bootstrap Angular bootstrap.css Poper
9.x.x         11.0.0    4.5.0   
10.x.x        12.0.0    4.5.0   
11.x.x        13.0.0    4.6.0   
12.x.x        13.0.0    5.0.0       2.10.2
13.x.x        14.1.0    5.2.0       2.10.2
14.x.x        15.0.0    5.2.3       2.11.6
```

So, if your app is in Angular 13, e.g. you need instal ng-bootstrap 12.x.x

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2
```

See that in [this link](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) you have the "changelog", so choose the bigger version according your version of Angular

NOTE: Perhaps you prefer upgrade your app to the most higher Angular version

Comment: Thanks sounds promising.  I am using Angular 15.1.0 and tried ng-bootstrap 14.0.0 and 14.0.1 but no luck.  I did create a brand new Angular project and then add bootstrap straight away before anything else and that was ok just struggling with an existing app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to delete `"node_modules"` folder and `"package-lock.json"` as well, and then run `npm i`

Answer (score 0):

Install bootstrap using npm : `npm i bootstrap .`
And then in `angular.json` file-> inside `"styles" array` add `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` and inside `script array` add `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"`

Comment: it's related to ng-bootstrap, not to bootstrap.